# EF Fluent API one-to-many relationship. On what end should I define it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

With the Entity Framework Fluent API there are relationships which can be defined on both participating classes. I was wondering if there are advantages or disadvantages of either solution.

Let me demonstrate. I have these classes:

```
public class GroupOfAnimals
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupOfAnimals Group { get; set; }
}
```

And the configurations:

```
public class GroupOfAnimalsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<GroupOfAnimals>
{
    public GroupOfAnimalsConfiguration ()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.ID);

        //Defining relationship #1
        HasMany(o => o.Members)
            .WithRequired(o => o.Group)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.GroupID);

    }
}

public class AnimalConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Animal>
{
    public AnimalConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.ID);

        //Defining relationship #2
        HasRequired(o => o.Group)
            .WithMany(o => o.Members)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.GroupID);
    }
}
```

As you can see both configurations contain the same one-to-many relationship. This is clearly redundant.

In contrast, with attributes it is clear what goes where in situations like this:

```
public class GroupOfAnimals
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Group")]
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group ")]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Members")]
    public virtual GroupOfAnimals Group { get; set; }
}
```

My question is:

Where should I define the relationship? On the group? On the animal? Is there any difference? Is there a clear convention I should follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships can be defined on either end.  It's up to you how you want to do it, but you should probably be consistent in whatever way you choose.

There is no advantage to using one way or another, they just give you the flexibility to define them in whichever manner makes the most sense to you.  You end up with the same relationship either way.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Gives me the confidence to choose what I feel is better knowing that either way is fine. I ended up defining the relationships on the side where the navigation properties are more direct, but made comments in the other sides' configuration to mark for other developers that the relationship is not forgotten, but it's configured elsewhere.